# Binding The content of a Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, grid

is there any way to bind the content (children) of a grid to a source of data of data(I mean objects)? for example binding the content of a grid to a list of buttons

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  If you have a code sample that would also be helpful.

Comment: Please, clarify your question.

Comment: @John bellow got my question that's exactly what I needed , thx any way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Binding to a collection you almost always want to use an `ItemsControl` or one of its derivatives. The `ItemsControl` will create a child for each item in a collection bound to its `ItemsSource` property and render them using the `ItemContainerStyle` and `ItemTemplate` and then put them each into the layout panel defined in the `ItemsPanel`. To use a Grid to do this layout you will need to put it into an `ItemsPanelTemplate` assigned to the `ItemsPanel` property and, if you want the items in specific rows and columns, also set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties in your `ItemContainerStyle` - either bound to data or calculated somehow.

Comment: thx @John that's exactly the explanation I needed.